# What is the fastest way to convert bytes to a boolean array containing each seperate bit in Scala?

Tags: algorithm, scala, optimization, huffman-code

After implementing the huffman algorithm in Scala and writing the results to a file I'm now working on building the decoder. To do that, I need to convert the `List[Char]` that I read from the file to a `List[Boolean]` containing each seperate bit. As it's a big file I need to do this in the fastest way possible.

I currently have the following algorithm:

```
def uncompress(fileString : String, fileChars : List[Char]) : String = {
 var bools:List[Boolean] = List[Boolean]()
    fileChars.foreach(f => bools = bools ++ byte2Bools(f))
}

 def byte2Bools(b: Char): Seq[Boolean] =
  0 to 7 map isBitSet(b)

def isBitSet(byte: Char)(bit: Int): Boolean =
  ((byte >> bit) & 1) == 1
```

However, completing this algorithm on a 600KB file takes more than 30 minutes! Also, I'm not sure if I may have made some mistakes creating this algorithm.

How can I improve this for better performance?

Comment: `bools ++ byte2Bools(f))`  While I don't have a direct answer, that peice of code is certainly part of the problem.  `++` is a terribly slow operation.  You aren't meant to append to Lists.  List also might not be the best structure to use because of its large memory overhead.  Consider using an Array or Vector and Look into the BitSet class for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fileChars.flatMap(byte2Bools)
```

will convert `List[Char]` to `List[Boolean]` much faster.

But using `List` with primitive types already means you have large memory overhead, and even more so for `Boolean`. I'd use `String` for the characters and `Array[Boolean]` or `BitSet` for bits (since you know the length in advance) to start with. Of course, this makes code more complicated...